# \begin{figure} makes the figure disappear

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have to make a bar chart in my latex document using `\begin{tikzpicture}`. I need to add a caption and label for this figure. Thus, I need to add `\begin{figure}`. However, it makes the figure disappear from the document. When I remove the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`, the figure appears but I can't add the caption. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Threshold},
        xtick={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        xmin=2, xmax=11,
        ymin=10, ymax=110,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east}
    ]
    \addplot[-, color=blue, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,100)(4,84.52)(5,84.76)(6,82.91)(7,83.24)(8,83.19)(9,82.64)(10,81.99)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Precision}
    \addplot[-, color=green, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,11.48)(4,69.84)(5,74.75)(6,85.90)(7,94.43)(8,97.38)(9,98.36)(10,100)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Recall}
    \addplot[dashed, color=red, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,20.59)(4,76.48)(5,79.44)(6,84.38)(7,88.48)(8,89.73)(9,89.82)(10,90.1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$F_1$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Accuracy performance with threshold}
\label{fig:threshold}
\end{figure}

\balance
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Yusufn probably issue with your LaTeX engine. I am able to see the caption properly with your code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you sure the figure has disappeared and not just floated to another position?

Comment: The MWE works fine for me as posted. Does it reproduce the issue for you or does the problem only become apparent in the context of a larger document? In the former case, please add an image of the output and upload your `.log` file. In the latter case, please try to edit your code example so that it reproduces the issue. Indeed this could just be an issue of the float floating to a different position, but there are rare situations where floats get lost: LaTeX will throw an error in that case to make you aware of the issue.

Comment: I have more than 4 figures and 3 tables in the document. It does not only figure, but also the table disappears when I add `\begin{table}`.

Comment: @marmot The figure disappears from the page, but the weird thing is there's an extra blank page at the end of the document.

Comment: @moewe May I share my document with you, so you can see the details? If yes, let me know your email.

Comment: with your document example is not possible to reproduce your problem.  that images/tables will stay nearby where they are inserted, add option `[htb] to `figure` and `table`: `\begin{figure}[htb]`.

Comment: I don't think I would be a great help. You have a much better chance of getting help by investing some time into creating a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the issue and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\balance`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Threshold},
        xtick={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        xmin=2, xmax=11,
        ymin=10, ymax=110,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east}
    ]
    \addplot[-, color=blue, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,100)(4,84.52)(5,84.76)(6,82.91)(7,83.24)(8,83.19)(9,82.64)(10,81.99)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Precision}
    \addplot[-, color=green, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,11.48)(4,69.84)(5,74.75)(6,85.90)(7,94.43)(8,97.38)(9,98.36)(10,100)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Recall}
    \addplot[dashed, color=red, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,20.59)(4,76.48)(5,79.44)(6,84.38)(7,88.48)(8,89.73)(9,89.82)(10,90.1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$F_1$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Accuracy performance with threshold}
\label{fig:threshold}
\end{figure}

%\balance
\end{document}
```

or add some text between `\balance` and `figure`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={},
        xlabel={Threshold},
        xtick={3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        xmin=2, xmax=11,
        ymin=10, ymax=110,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east}
    ]
    \addplot[-, color=blue, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,100)(4,84.52)(5,84.76)(6,82.91)(7,83.24)(8,83.19)(9,82.64)(10,81.99)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Precision}
    \addplot[-, color=green, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,11.48)(4,69.84)(5,74.75)(6,85.90)(7,94.43)(8,97.38)(9,98.36)(10,100)
        };
        \addlegendentry{Recall}
    \addplot[dashed, color=red, smooth]
        coordinates{
        (3,20.59)(4,76.48)(5,79.44)(6,84.38)(7,88.48)(8,89.73)(9,89.82)(10,90.1)
        };
        \addlegendentry{$F_1$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Accuracy performance with threshold}
\label{fig:threshold}
\end{figure}

This is some text

\balance
\end{document}
```

[image]